# The WinForms designer code is changed whenever I add new control

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I add a `UltraListView` Control in my form, which is from Infragistics. And I manually add an event in the designer.cs like below:

```
this.ultraListView1.ItemSelectionChanged += ultraListView1_ItemSelectionChanged;
```

It will be called when I change the selected item in `UltraListView`. And it works very well. But when I add some controls to the form, this line will disappear. So I need to manually add it again and again.
How can I fix it?

Comment: `I manually add a event`  Where are you adding it?

Comment: If you add it into a function that is generated by the compiler like `InitializeComponent` then it is expected. You need to add you event handler elsewhere in your code. If you use the IDE as intended, then partial class is automatically generated and you should rarely have to modify that file. Also remember that often when you add an event handler manually, just have to remove it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the Infragistics control is the same way as with all the WinForms controls.

- Open your dialog in the Designer.
- Right click on the control will open the following popup menu. Select `Properties`:

[image]

- In the `Properties` window click on the `Events` button and scroll to
  find out required event. Then double-click on the required event:

[image]

The Visual Studio Designer will add the selected event handler and open it code for editing.

Comment: thank you! I am a novice in winform, even don't know event can be added like this...Really helps me

Comment: @Rikcy Chu: The Infragistics controls have very rich set of properties to be tuning by the designer very easy. But when editing `*.designer.cs` files manually be ready that those changes might be lost after feature changing dialogs in the designer, or the Visual Studio designer won't be able to open dialogs for editing at all.

Answer (score -1):

.

The most important here to know here is how to find out the issues.

In your solution, go to Tools -> Options. Choose Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and select Diagnostic in “MSbuild project build output verbosity”.

[image]